# How to find the pressed button

Tags: forms

Help me please. How can I get the value of the pressed button. Thanks!

$items = [];

```
foreach ($result as &$value) {
  $items[] = [
    $form['repo'] = [
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#title' => $this
        ->t('FIELD REPO'),
    ],
    $form['repo']['repo_name'] = [
      '#type' => 'item',
      '#title' => $value->name,
    ],
    $form['repo']['user_name'] = [
      '#type' => 'hidden',
      '#title' => $value->name,
      '#value' => $value->name,
    ],
    $form['repo']['submit'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $value->name,
    ],
  ];
}
$form['repositories_arr'] = [
  '#theme' => 'item_list',
  '#items' => $items,
  '#attributes' => ['id' => 'repositories_arr'],
];




return $form;
```

Comment: None of the above are inputs, so where are you trying to get a value from?

Answer (score 0):

In the `foreach` loop of your example, you create multiple buttons and you can set a different/distinct `'#name'` property property to each submit button, e.g.:

```
foreach ($result as &$value) {
  ...
  $form['repo']['submit'] = [
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => $value->name,
    '#name' => $value->name,
  ];
  ...
}
```

In your validation and/or submit handler you can retrieve the element that triggered the form submission using [`$form_state->getTriggeringElement()['#name']`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormState.php/function/FormState%3A%3AgetTriggeringElement).

Comment: @Good Media, I'm not sure why you need `&$value` in your `foreach` loop and I don't think/understand the assigning part to `$form['repo'][<properties>]` either.

Comment: $form_state->getTriggeringElement()['#name']   This returned last button in my list. Regardless of which button I click

Comment: @GoodMedia, did you set distinct values for the `'#name'` property (of each submit button)? What I would do is create two extra buttons outside your for each and set two values, e.g., `'#name' => 'button_1'` and `'#name' => 'button_2'`. In your form submission handler, $form_state->getTriggeringElement()['#name'] should give you `'button_1'` when you pressed the first and `'button_2'` in case you pressed the second one.

Answer (score 0):

So, what i wanted ...

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr_git); $i++) {
  $form[] = [
    $item['repo_name'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#title' => 'name'.$i,
      '#prefix' => '<div class="form__item">',
      '#attributes' => ['class' => ['item_name']],
    ],
    $item['repo_del'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#name' => 'NA::ME___' . $i,
      '#value' => 'Delete',
      '#attributes' => ['class' => ['btn_del']],
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
    ],
  ];
}]

return $form;
```

This is then what made it work:

```
$form_state->getTriggeringElement()['#name'];
```

I rendered the form incorrectly

[image]

Comment: Good to see that you have solved your problem! But I don't think this is a real answer to your (original) question, I recommend you to update your question with the relevant source code and edit (or comment) on the answer that did answer your question.

Comment: This method ---> $form_state->getTriggeringElement()['#name'] <--- really search for the pressed button in form and return #name or #value or other attributes, but, this method in my old code from my question return always  the last button from my list form. So, I made a decision correct my form.

Comment: No, what made it work was using a different value for `'#name'` for each submission button, but similar thing should be done for other fields too.